# MSXML uses wininet when loads a xml file from a \\share

Tags: wininet, xmlhttprequest

We know we should not use MSXML from Classic ASP to load remote xml files, because the WinInet is not designed for server use.

Do you know if loading a xml file from \\server\sharefolder also loads wininet?

Should we use ServerXmlHTTP instead?

Thx

rido

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if loading a xml file from \server\sharefolder also loads wininet?

I can't guarantee that it doesn't, but I would be *shocked* if it did. WinINET, as its name implies, is used for connections using internet protocols, while `\\server\sharefolder` implies a SMB connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSXML DOM document to load xml in a server-safe way by turning on [ServerHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766434%28VS.85%29.aspx) property. The downside is that the load method will have to perform in a sync way.